# Advice on refactoring a regex character class subtraction

Tags: c#, .net, regex, mono

Mono's Regex implementation has a bug which means it does not handle regex character class subtraction correctly.

IE: "[ab-[a]]" should in effect be the character set "[b]".

For example the following code on .NET will output "The\ncat\nsat\non\nthe\nmat".
This example contains the simplified regex that I am trying to make work on mono.

```
string listOfUnicodeChars = "\u2e80";  
string patten =  
"[\\p{Lu}\\p{Ll}\\p{Lt}\\p{Lo}‌‍\\p{Mn}\\p{Mc}\\p{Lm}-[" + listofUnicodeChars +"]]+";

Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
foreach (var match in regex.Matches("The cat sat on the mat."))
   Console.WriteLine(match);
```

but using mono the regex matches nothing.

Does anyone have any suggestions about how to get the same affect with the regex written a different way?

Comment: Is there a paren missing in your pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered using a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)? Such as:

```
"(?![" + listOfUnicodeChars + "])[\\p{Lu}" + ... + "]"
```

Comment: Thanks for the example and link. Negative lookahead seems to work well on mono.

Comment: +1. So the full regex would be `"(?:(?!EXCLUDE)INCLUDE)+"`, where INCLUDE and EXCLUDE are your two character classes.

Comment: Right. My example matches one character only.